# $F({x+y\over 1+xy}) = F(x)\cdot F(y)$ for all real $x, y$ except $-1$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, functional-equations

If $F(x)$ is a differentiable function that satisfies the above functional equation for all real x and y except -1.
If $F(0) \ne 0$ and $F'(0) = 1$ then $F(x) = ? $

Comment: I assume "!=" means "not equals"?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I did not realise that it could be misinterpreted as factorial.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $x=\tan x_1$ and $y=\tan y_1$ with $|x_1|<{\pi\over 2}$ and $|y_1|<{\pi\over 2}$. Then by defining $$g(x)=e^{f(\tan x)}$$ we have $$g(x_1+y_1)=g(x_1)+g(y_1)$$

Comment: I don't think that's working!  But I did find the answer by exploiting the fact that the function is said to differentiable. F(x) turned out to be ((1+x)/(1-x))^(0.5)